# what is the correct scala version to use for spark?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am confuse about which scala I should use. I got this error when I run spark-submit application:

```
17/06/05 06:59:46 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw 
exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
    at com.xxx.push_up.App$.main(App.scala:255)
    at com.xxx.push_up.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:637)
```

I found it is because of the imcompatibility of scala between compiling and excution. I use this code to check the runtime scala version:

```
println("SparkContext version: "+ sc.version)
println("Scala version: "+ scala.tools.nsc.Properties.versionString)
```

The output is :

```
SparkContext version: 2.1.1
Scala version: version 2.11.8
```

My pom.xml is :

```
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaCompatVersion>2.11.8</scalaCompatVersion>
                    <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependences>
....
```

I don't know what is going wrong. Thanks.

---

the code for error in App.scala:255:

```
val gcm_log_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(gcm_log_raw_rdd.filter(_.length == 12), gcm_log_raw_schema).filter("pid != 'unknown'").select("pid","channel")
```

It is the first time i use sqlContext, i think it triger the problem.

---

I add the scala dependence, still the same problem:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>            
   <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The exception occurs as App.scala line 25. can you post the content of your code at this location with -+ 5 lines of code?

Comment: did you include the scala library dependency in your pom file? I guess you forgot that.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I add the dependence, still the same problem. i switch the program from 1.6.1 to spark 2.1.1 because there are problems using collect_list in 1.6.1, at that project, i din't include scala dependence and could run the rest code normally.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is mainly due to either necessary library is missing or there is a conflict in the version. I didn't see scala library dependency in your pom file. try to include `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>` and if the error still exists then you will have to check for conflicting scala library in your project.

Comment: Did you also upgrade your spark cluster ? Is it running in the cloud ?

Comment: yes, it is running

Comment: Can you please provide more information about that please  ? AWS EMR or GC Dataflow ? This is important ! And answer comments with the @eliasah if you wish to notify me of update or i'll not get your message...

Comment: Please provide your POM.xml in the question and not a subset of it

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check the required Scala version is to take a look at `jars/` that come along with your Spark.

```
ls path-to-your-spark/spark/jars | grep scala
```

You should see something like:

```
jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.0.jar
json4s-scalap_2.12-3.7.0-M5.jar
scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.1.jar
scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar
scala-library-2.12.10.jar
scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.2.jar
scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar
scala-xml_2.12-1.2.0.jar
```

And `scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar` should tell you which version is required. In my case, it is `2.12`